# How do I give multiple buttons a similar code?

Tags: c#

I am trying to build a chess game in a Windows form (one of my first windows form projects) and I have 64 buttons (one for each square on the board).

The squares / buttons should have similar code and work with each other.

How do I do it without writing a ton of duplicate code for every square?

Comment: Why not just a for loop?

Comment: `Similar` code or `the same code`?

Comment: can you explain more? vlad

Comment: @HardCode I suppose it'd be *same code* with *different* values of variables (like `x,y` coords).

Comment: @YuAm: The idea is that you shouldn't create buttons by dropping them from the toolbox, but have a loop and create the buttons, attach event handlers and place onto the main form from within a loop.

Answer (score 0):

lets say that you want tou implement *Click Event*

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     ///implementation
     Button btn = (Button) sender;
     //do your work with your button
}
```

then just you need to register `Button_Click` method for all your button's Click Event